# select between two table in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity-relationship

I want to write a select between two table that have relation.
I use this code but i get no result.
Please advise me

```
 using (doctorEntities de = new doctorEntities())
        {
            var select = from tibase in de.Table_infobase_print
                         from tidetail in de.Table_infodetail_print
                         where tibase.ID == tidetail.ID_infobase 
                         select new
                         {
                             tidetail.services_discription,tidetail.price,tibase.folder_code
                         };
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for a **join** instead, regardless you should be getting results if you have matching rows in the database. Also currently you are not doing anything with the results.

```
using (doctorEntities de = new doctorEntities())
{
    var results = from tibase in de.Table_infobase_print
                  join tidetail in de.Table_infodetail_print
                  on tibase.ID equals tidetail.ID_infobase 
                  select new
                  {
                      tidetail.services_discription,
                      tidetail.price,
                      tibase.folder_code
                  };
    foreach(var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service description: " + result.services_discription);
    }
}
```